discord.py (with cogs) + FastAPI: errno -3 temporary failure in name resolution [solved while posting]
I've got what I would consider a fairly basic attempt at starting discord.py under FastAPI.
It just crashes with errno -3 temporary failure in name resolution
I've included most of the relevant code, in case I'm overlooking something simple.
@typechecked
class UnfilteredBot(Bot):
    async def process_commands(self, message:Message)->None:
        """ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68581659/i-want-my-bot-to-process-commands-sent-by-other-bots """
        ctx:Context = await self.get_context(message)
        await self.invoke(ctx)

@typechecked
class MyBot(UnfilteredBot):
    def __init__(self, command_prefix:str='!')->None:
        """ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30633889/typeerror-super-does-not-take-key-word-arguments """
        intents: Intents        = Intents.default()
        #intents.members        = True
        # allow to get commands from GC
        intents.message_content = True  # v2
        super().__init__(intents=intents, command_prefix=command_prefix)

@typechecked
def get_app(token:str, guild:str, channel:int, rest_key:str)->FastAPI:
    shutdown         :Event          = Event() # from threading import Event
    #complete         :Event          = Event()
    app              :FastAPI        = FastAPI()
    bot              :Bot            = MyBot()

    @app.on_event("startup")
    async def startup_event()->Coroutine[None]: # this function will run before the main API starts
        """ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65460672/expose-discord-bot-to-api-flask-fastapi """
        #await bot.add_cog(BasicCog  (bot))
        #await bot.add_cog(MessageCog(bot, channel, ai_bot_pipe))

        bot_start:Coroutine[None] = bot.start(token)
        create_task( bot_start )

    @app.on_event("shutdown")
    async def shutdown_event()->Coroutine[None]:
        """ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75975807/how-to-stop-a-loop-on-shutdown-in-fastapi """
        shutdown.set()
        #while not complete.wait(1): # gently stop a different bot's loop
        #    await sleep(1) # work-around for follow-up question
        #    print("waiting")
    return app

@typechecked
def main()->None:
    load_dotenv  () # from dotenv import load_dotenv
    token            :str            =     environ['DISCORD_TOKEN']
    guild            :str            =     environ['DISCORD_GUILD']
    channel          :int            = int(environ['DISCORD_CHANNEL'])
    host             :str            =      getenv('HOST', 'locahost') # <-- nevermind, guys. I found it
    port             :int            =      getenv('PORT',       5000)
    setup_logging() # from discord.utils import setup_logging
    app              :FastAPI        = get_app(token, guild, channel, rest_key)
    urun(app, host=host, port=port) # from uvicorn import run as urun

if __name__ == '__main__':
    exit(main())

pre-post update:
Solved. I'll go ahead and post anyway, since I couldn't find an example with cogs and graceful termination
follow-up:
having trouble gracefully terminating the other bot. I guess the threading.Event solution is for threads. Go figure. The loop function stops iterating completely, so the finally block is never executed, so the fastapi server never finishes shutting down
    async def start(self)->Coroutine[None]:
        """ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37278647/fire-and-forget-python-async-await/37345564#37345564 """
        try:
            print('AI.start() try')
            while not self.shutdown.wait(1):
                print('AI.start() loop')
                
                await sleep(1) #???
                pass
        finally:
            print('AI.start() finally')
            #self.shutdown.set() # assert is set ?
            self.complete.set()
        print('AI.start() done')

I found an Event_ts based on asyncio.Event. The other bot I mentioned was originally from a threaded application, so it's got the threading.Event code. I think I need to implement a similar sort of timed wait() to do this cleanly. Either that or Event_ts is not applicable here... since I'm switching from threads to coroutines.

Reading the 'similar question' here:
FastAPI, asyncpg (postgres) and Docker: wsocket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
Made me wonder why in the world "localhost" would cause a problem... and then I noticed the typo.
For the follow-up problem: I'm using booleans as a work-around since it's not multi-threaded. Until I can figure out a way to exit that while loop as soon as the other bot sets its termination flag.

You can use a synchronization primitive like asyncio.Condition for the follow-up problem.

I think I'm gonna have to make it a separate question. I'm having trouble with notify(). And I get a feeling this might be the solution to my next problem... which is that the dumb-bot and AI are locking up if I don't use _nowait() ops with the queue
